# Как подключиться к RCON серверу из PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, java, c#, c++

Есть простенькая задача... Попросили подключиться к RCON серверу из PHP... Есть готовые библиотеки, я быстренько их заюзал, думал, что работы на 5 минут... но не тут-то было... Оказалось не всё так просто, потому как не работает)

Не поделитесь своим опытом, может кто пробывал, экспериментировал с этим RCON?

Рассмотрю примеры на любых языках программирования...

Comment: Что такое "RCON сервер"?

Answer (score 1):

Я лично пользуюсь https://github.com/xPaw/PHP-Source-Query, там уже есть пример отправки команд RconExample.php

Comment: Не получается почему-то... Что может быть?

Comment: Failed to read any data from socket

#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\rcon7\SourceQuery\Socket.php(76): xPaw\SourceQuery\BaseSocket->ReadInternal(Object(xPaw\SourceQuery\Buffer), 1400, Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\rcon7\SourceQuery\SourceQuery.php(210): xPaw\SourceQuery\Socket->Read()
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\rcon7\Examples\View.php(26): xPaw\SourceQuery\SourceQuery->GetInfo()
#3 {main}

Comment: @sitev_ru В вопросе не указано какая игра, но мне кажется именно от этого зависит. Вот вопрос с похожей проблемой https://github.com/xPaw/PHP-Source-Query/issues/92